# What is the Puppeteer equivalent of this Selenium code that finds an element by css and clicks on it?

Tags: selenium, puppeteer

I am trying to parse banking website and I have the whole workflow recorded in Selenium and everything works. Due to inability to persist cookies between sessions while using Selenium Webdriver (Cookies cannot be loaded - "missing name exception") I moved to puppeteer. Line by line it went good until I got the following lines:

In selenium:

`await driver.findElement(By.css(".buttons:nth-child(4)")).click()`

and in puppeteer

`await page.frames()[1].click('.buttons:nth-child(4)');`

does not work.

What is funny though:

`await page.frames()[1].waitForSelector('.buttons:nth-child(4)');`

does not throw exception so element is present on the page.

Comment: Could you add a sentence that ends with a question mark? It's hard to tell what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page.frames() will return a promise. You have to await almost everything:

```
let frames = await page.frames()
await frames[1].click('.buttons:nth-child(4)');
```

Comment: Thanks. It made the whole code look cleaner and it helped me in thinking:-) It started to work when I added '''await page.waitFor(5000);''' anyway before click - any Ideas why waitforselector resolves and in fact this selector is missing? Or how to understand this behaviour?